# Python delete line from (multiple) file(S)

Tags: python, filter, printing, line

I am new to python I search already for whole day and evening to some code to just read line and print it to console 
My goal is to filter on word and delete some line

I found only 1 piece of code that does the job but there is a bug in it

All the example for me to learn about just printing DO NOT WORK al ALL

Some of the error i get back

```py
IndentationError: unexpected indent

return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1929: character maps to <undefined>
```

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.Did you mean print(line)?
```

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

These are just some of the errors
I assume i miss some packages in python???

The code that works does not filter correct

```
with open('C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\NF\\NL.txt', 'rb') as file_in:
with open("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\NF\\new.txt", "wb") as file_out:
    file_out.writelines(filter(lambda line: b'ADM1' and b'ADM2' in line, file_in))
```

Filter is ADM1 and ADM2 
However the textfile also has lines containing ADM2H and the output file should only has ADM1 and ADM2 but i get all the variations that has ADM2 in it as well

How can i filter on exact word and can someone please provide me sample code of just printing all the lines in a text file
Also i would like to have a piece of code that will execute the code above on multiple files 
I cant find any online that does the job

Many thanks in advance for helping a rooky out

Comment: Just found out that the file i am using is  utf-8 
Added encoding='utf-8' and not i can use most of the examples found online

Still i am not able to filter correct and write to file

Answer (score -1):

Found it 
Reason for the examples i found is that my file is UTF-8 
After adding the encoding='utf-8' the script is working just fine

```
with open("Yourfile.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in new_f:
        if "PPL" not in line:
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```